# The snmpV3 connection failed with error on the substratefungt error takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, snmp

I tried to connect using snmpV3 but i get errors the thig is that when I trying the same code on the same device in another copmuter its passed successfully I tried to upgrade all the pasckeges in the python but it's didnt help
the code is:

```
  snmpv3_obj = Snmp(sbc_dut.management_ip, Snmp.SnmpVersion.SNMPv3, username='user_a', authpswrd=password_auth,
                      privacypswrd=password_priv,
                      authprotocol="SHA-1", privacyprotocol="AES-128")
    oid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"
    try:
snmp_val = snmpv3_obj.get_snmp_value([oid])[oid]
```

its failed on the last line that this is the connection(the function is craete by me but it using python packe)
this is the get_snmp_value:

```
    def get_snmp_value(self, oids):
        """
        The get_snmp_value procedure is for retrieving the value of an individual object in the snmp MIB

        :param oids: a list of Object IDs
        :return: value of an individual snmp object
        :rtype: dict
        """
        handler = hlapi.getCmd(
            self._engine,
            self._credentials_get,
            hlapi.UdpTransportTarget((self._target, self._port)) if type(ip_address(self._target)) is IPv4Address else hlapi.Udp6TransportTarget((self._target, self._port)),
            self._context,
            *Snmp._construct_object_types(oids)
        )
        return Snmp._fetch(handler, 1)[0]
```

and this is the error:
The Exception is :poll error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dispatch.py", line 45, in runDispatcher
    loop(timeout or self.getTimerResolution(),
;  File "C:\Users\qabsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 214, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
;  File "C:\Users\qabsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 157, in poll
    read(obj)
;  File "C:\Users\qabsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 94, in read
    obj.handle_error()
;  File "C:\Users\qabsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 90, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
;  File "C:\Users\qabsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 427, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\base.py", line 170, in handle_read
    self._cbFun(self, transportAddress, incomingMessage)
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\base.py", line 84, in _cbFun
    self.__recvCallables[recvId](
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\entity\engine.py", line 151, in __receiveMessageCbFun
    self.msgAndPduDsp.receiveMessage(
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\rfc3412.py", line 291, in receiveMessage
    msgVersion = verdec.decodeMessageVersion(wholeMsg)
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\api\verdec.py", line 15, in decodeMessageVersion
    seq, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 2003, in __call__
    for asn1Object in streamingDecoder:
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1918, in __iter__
    for asn1Object in self._singleItemDecoder(
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1778, in __call__
    for value in concreteDecoder.valueDecoder(
;  File "C:\Projects\PyBREnv\venv\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 654, in valueDecoder
    for chunk in substrateFun(asn1Object, substrate, length, options):
;TypeError: decodeMessageVersion.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
caused by <class 'TypeError'>: decodeMessageVersion.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
15-06-2023 11:42:03.912093  SCRIPT  ScriptLogger    INFO    call - Deleting the user
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyasn1/pyasn1/issues/28